# MongodB object array query

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to figure out how to search object array, which has label "작성" and value is "Y"
I made find query like this `{"attrs.label": "작성" , "attrs.value": "Y"}`
But the problem is
`{..., attrs: [{label: "작성", value: "N"}, {label: "Another", value: "Y"}]}`
this document was matched with my query I need full match in one array element.

**I tried**

`{  $and: [{"attrs.label": /작성/}, {"attrs.value": "Y"}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to indicate that at least one array item has to fullfill all the requirements:

```
db.collection.find({ attrs: { $elemMatch: { label: "작성", value: "Y" } } })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NogblUfDgLH)